# How to use a server to store/receive data?

Tags: android

I am wondering what is required to setup a server so that you can store data on it, and then have an application send requests to it to store and receive data. More specifically, I am working on an Android application where a user will generate data and then that should be stored on a server so other users can access it. But I do not know how setting up a server to be capable of this works. I have worked on Android applications in the past that sends requests (put, post, get, etc) to a server, but that back end was already set up for me. Any info or resources about setting this up would be great.

Answer (score 7):

There are many, many different ways to accomplish this.

Since you're already working with a Google technology, Android - you could start by creating a Google App Engine project. Following the tutorials you can get started setting up a simple back end solution that will store data for you and you can make requests to it for that data.

Another advantage to this for you is that you don't have to learn how to install software on a server and all the dependencies that arise from that, etc. Simply set up a new account and push-button deploy through Eclipse or command line.

And since you've used Java in Android, you can use JAva for Google App Engine (GAE) too!

Getting started: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/introduction.html

Comment: Excellent this is exactly what I was looking for, but what are some options if you don't want to excursively be on Android, what should you use if you want to have an Android and iOS application.

Comment: If you like GAE, you can use it as a backend for any platform. The requests to the server for data don't need to know where the request is coming from or what client is being used. It also helps if you mark this as the answer : )

Answer (score 0):

You can try ready to use BAAS/PAAS services to store your data, e.g. QuickBlox for Android http://quickblox.com/developers/Android, where you can manipulate with your data with few strings

```
QBLocation location = new QBLocation();
location.setLatitude(35.0);
location.setLongitude(53.0);
location.setStatus("I'm at this place");

String someImportantString = "Dr. Henry Walton Indiana Jones";

QBLocations.createLocation(location, new QBCallbackImpl() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(Result result, Object context) {
        // retrieve context object inside callback
        String passedContextObject = (String) context;
        System.out.println(passedContextObject);

        // do stuff with result
    }
}, someImportantString);
```

All logic of data exchange with server is encapsulated in framework.